# "no explicit type for the object index" when grouping object array by its property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have an array of `Product`.

The `Product` class:

```
class Product {
    id: string;
    type: string;
    price: number;
    constructor(id: string, type: string, price: number) {
        this.id = id;
        this.type = type;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

I try to group the array of product by its `type` property by using the [array reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) function:

```
const groupedProducts = productList.reduce((group, prod) => {
    const prodType = prod.type;
    group[prodType] = group[prodType] ?? [];
    group[prodType].push(prod);
    return group;
}, {});
```

Above code gets compiler error:

```
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.
```

I see that it is because of the initial value `{}` has no explicit type for the object index, so I refactored the initial value part from `{}` to `{string: Product[]}`. But it doesn't help.

The full code is [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEAKAnA9gEwK4gC6wN7FkNgEtUAuWKLRYgOwHMBuAorATwAcBTCqmh5kVgcaIHrFroAtgCMuiQURDJafTFmSIAFKV7U69ADSx23PfyPDR4ybPkBKPCyGEsAC2JQAdKVgBeElRFFxMPb1MufxNOLmCXd08vEWIxKOSxOIBfYGzgUBUqKzQARijaLgB3BBQMbC0AcmL643rlKQ50LHlm2GKABgH7ZmVVHBE0ACYyyuq0dQaJnvqAM2Q0Hom%20ofzRotQAZmmqpDm6%20v2l8GR3HoA2W%202RwvHUABYj2dqsBtfL5HbOt1jP1BsMCmMagBWD4nL4NSGXMDXNx3SGPcF7W4wmrzeq3JardbArbMHbPHHYAAyniwFFh6gA2gBdKLM0kvdTUqhJdBQNxaF7FbYcqk0nl8gU1CbCilYLlYcX8l77GWnOVijoSl6vVVfeWKyVoNHMEXq7mapU1B6kp44egodDcVD07BwAKm-WILi1LhaLT25CO4wvRx%20AB8TiEtr2ABUYmkal4InEA46GS849wWQFUxx0zVM1wWQB%20YuwNnOWC5-NoQtMg0huJerDoRC0KsOjjMTLGXCZbZk5BgLheJH0LQAAwASgBRADKAFVKTGKAASXAAKTnAHkAHJePgGYjLNj%20zvel1YKD2TIToZAA).

How can I get rid of this error & get the grouped products as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct approach would probably be to specify the generic type of `reduce` explicitly.

```
const groupedProducts = productList.reduce<Record<string, Product[]>>((group, prod) => {
    const prodType = prod.type;
    group[prodType] = group[prodType] ?? [];
    group[prodType].push(prod);
    return group;
}, {});
```

This correctly types the `group` parameter and the return type as `Record<string, Product[]>`.

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYwNghgzlAEAKAnA9gEwK4gC6wN7FkNgEtUAuWKLRYgOwHMBuAorATwAcBTCqmh5kVgcaIHrFroAtgCMuiQURDJafTFmSIAFKV7U69ADSx23PfyPDR4ybPkBKPCyGEsAC2JQAdKVgBeElRFFxMPb1MufxNOLmCXd08vEWIxKOSxOIBfYGzgUBUqKzQARijaLgB3BBQMbC0AcmL643rlKQ50LHlm2GKABgH7ZmVVHBE0ACYyyuq0dQaJnvqAM2Q0Hom+ofzRotQAZmmqpDm6+v2l8GR3HoA2W+2RwvHUABYj2dqsBtfL5HbOt1jP1BsMCmMagBWD4nL4NSGXMDXNx3SGPcF7W4wmrzeq3JardbArbMHbPHHYAAyniwFFh6gA2gBdKLM0kvdTUqhJdBQNxaF7FbYcqk0nl8gU1CbCilYLlYcX8l77GWnOVijoSl6vVVfeWKyVoNHMEXq7mapU1B6kp44egodDcVD07BwAKm-WILi1LgAHgASlxlIhUL6+AZjC6sMyAHwxrRae3IR3GF6OPwxpxCW17AAqMTSNS8ETiScdDJe+e4LICZY4FZqVa4LIA-C3YGznLA6w20E2mQa03EvVh0IhaN2HRxmJljLhMtsycgwFwvEj6FoAAb+gCiAGUAKqU3MUAAkuAAUnuAPIAOS84YYxGWbETU+9Uag9kym6GQA)